# Unusually large favicon generated by ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, icons

I am generating a favicon image using the following ImageMagick script:

```
convert src/favicon.svg \
        \( -clone 0 -resize 16x16 \) \
        \( -clone 0 -resize 32x32 \) \
        \( -clone 0 -resize 48x48 \) \
    -delete 0 -colors 256 -bordercolor transparent -border 10% -background transparent \
        site/public/favicon.ico
```

This produces an ISO of 22KiB, which seems a little large because the following produces a PNG of 3.4K:

```
convert src/favicon.svg -resize 48x48 -colors 256 -bordercolor transparent -border 10% -background transparent 48.png
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong that increases the filesize? There is only one color in the image and the background is transparent:

[image]

By all accounts it should be a really small file size I'd imagine.

Comment: It would be a good idea to give a link to your SVG file so that we can test your command. Did you try the `+antialias` option?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an ImageMagick expert, but in some experiments I did with an example svg file I noticed that an `identify favicon.ico` showed the resulting file to be using 32-bit pixels, whereas the `48.png` was a different depth, 16 in my case. By moving the `-colors 256` option to be last in the argument list, I ended up with a more appropriate depth of 8-bit and a favicon file of about half the original size.